# registerReceiver from IntentService doesn't hit BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-download-manager

I've created an `IntentService` for downloading a file using Android's DownloadManager. Following is my Class:

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {

   public DownloadService() {
        super("name");
    }

    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            function();
         }
       };

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
        Utility.download(someURL);

       }

    }
```

I've this entry in manifest:

```
        <service
            android:name=".services.DownloadService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
```

The code inside `BroadcastReceiver(function())` is never executing even if the file is downloaded. I also tried doing the same thing in `Service` instead of `IntentService`, it worked.
How can I make BroadcastReceiver work inside IntentService?

Comment: I think you need to register your broadcast receiver in the android manifest, rather than setting it programatically. The system needs to know that your application can handle DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE intents

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754302/registerreceiver-inside-intentservice-tracking-smsmanager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid calling `registerReceiver` method using IntentService's context.

Once your [IntentService#onHandleIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) method returns, the [Service#stopSelf(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf(int)) method will be called. All the not-yet-unregistered receivers will be considered as leaked. The framework even warns you about that:

```
E/ActivityThread﹕ Service com.your.packagename.YourIntentService has leaked IntentReceiver com.your.packagename.YourReceiver@41f4cd08 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.your.packagename.YourIntentService has leaked IntentReceiver com.your.packagename.YourReceiver@41f4cd08 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:796)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:597)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1438)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1418)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1412)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
    at com.your.packagename.YourIntentService.onHandleIntent(YourIntentService.java:79)
    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

And of course, none of your leaked broadcast receivers will receive notifications afterwards.

If you still want to register the broadcast receiver within [IntentService#onHandleIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) method, use (for example) Application's context for that.

```
getApplication().registerReceiver(receiverInstance,  
        new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Note however, that you'll have to add logic that unregisters each such receiver instance once you finish with it.

Comment: what would you suggest if I want the registered receiver to get triggered even after the application has been closed. If I use getApplication context it wouldn't get triggered.

Comment: @AraYeressian You can declare your receiver in manifest and enable/disable it according to your logic using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29